# Serilog logging in multi-project Blazor Server application

Tags: blazor-server-side, serilog

I'm using Serilog in a Blazor Server application that runs  on .Net Core 6. The application has multiple projects and Serilog is configured in the main UI project Program.cs. Inside the UI project, logging works fine, but, using the static Log I am unable to get any log output in any of the child projects. This is the configuration I have in Program.cs.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console( LogEventLevel.Debug )
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();

Log.Information( "Starting application" );

try
{
    WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder( args );

    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json", false, true )
            .SetBasePath( builder.Environment.ContentRootPath )
           // appsettings{env}.json is not committed to the repo, use it to override settings (e.g. connection string) based on the environment.
           .AddJsonFile( $"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", false, true );

    builder.Host.UseSerilog( ( ctx, lc ) => lc
       .WriteTo.Console()
       .ReadFrom.Configuration( ctx.Configuration ) );

    ...
    
    WebApplication app = builder.Build();
    
    ...
    
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    
    app.Run();
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    Log.Fatal( ex, "Unhandled exception." );
}
finally
{
    Log.Information( "Shutting down the application." );
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

In a service inside the Infrastructure project I have

```
using Serilog;
...
Log.Information( "A log entry that never shows up." );
```

I have looked through other similar SO questions and Serilog setup examples, but none of the solutions have made any difference when I tried them. What step am I missing to get this working?

Comment: Log.Logger in the Ui app is also with the Serilog namespace?